# Get Entity by Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

Say I have a list of EF entity names like:

```
List<string> entityNames = new List<string>(){
    "Table1",
    "Table2",
    "Table3"
};
```

From this list of entities I want to query each entity individually, similar to:

```
var result = efContext.Table1.Where(t => ...);
```

Using reflection, or black magic, how would I obtain a reference to the actual entity so that I could wind up with something like:

```
foreach(var e in entityNames)
{
    var entity = efcontext.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == e).Single();
    var result = efContext.entity.Where(t => ...);
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please do not include Entity Framework in your title. That is what tags are for

Comment: What you actually want to achieve or what are you upto?

Comment: What I want to do is take a list of table names, get the corresponding entities, and run the same LINQ statement against each entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that all of the Entity types listed implement some common interface that you intend to use in your `Where` clause, you could do something like this:

```
foreach(var e in entityNames)
{
    PropertyInfo entityProperty = efcontext.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == e).Single();
    var baseQuery = (IQueryable<IMyEntity>)entity.GetValue(efContext, null);
    var result = baseQuery.Where(t => ...);
}
```

Comment: My query would be something like:
`.Where(t => t.DateStampField > aPredeterminedDate);`

Comment: @PhilScholtes: Right, so your `IMyEntity` interface would need to include a `DateStampField`.

Comment: You can shorten `efcontext.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == e).Single();` to `efcontext.GetType().GetProperty(e);`